# SQL: How to set a column to a maximum value?

Tags: mysql, sql, linux, mariadb

This is my first question, might not be the last, alrighty then,
In table jobs, I have

```
job_id int pk a_i not null,
job_title varchar(20) not null,
min_salary decimal(5,2),
max_salary decimal(5,2)
```

The answer to which I am looking an alternative is:

```
job_id int pk a_i not null,
job_title varchar(20) not null,
min_salary decimal(5,2),
max_salary decimal(5,2) check (max_salary<=10000)
```

My quest is to find an equation to set the **maximum value of `max_salary` to 10000.**

Query executed:

[image]

Comment: Question is not clear. That max salary should not take anything more than value specified? Or it should default to this value? Or you want to find what maximum it could take as in dec(5,2)?

Comment: `decimal(5,2)` can store values from -999.99 to 999.99 only (Error message "Out of range value for column 'max_salary' at row N" will be produced when the value is out of this range).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry everyone if I didn't properly elaborate my question.
So after a long night of Trials&Errors:

> ALTER table table_name
> add CHECK (max_salary<=10000);

And voila! so if i enter value 10001, I usually get an error, which is good!

Thank You for the fast replies anyway!